# Set height on react-select using styled-components doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-select

I'm using react-select 3.0.8 and styled-components 4.3.2, but when I set the height it's showing like a height in the background instead of changing the input height.

[image]

```
const SearchInput = styled(Select)`
  height: 90px;
  width: 590px;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Monserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: medium;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #444;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 22px;
  outline: none;
`;
```

....

```
<SearchInput
    value={selected}
    options={options}
    placeholder="Search a city"
    isSearchable="true"
    components={{ DropdownIndicator:() => null, 
      IndicatorSeparator:() => null }}
  />
```

Comment: Are you sure that react-select doesn't have some wrapper that you style isnted of input?

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: yes it is, look in api or here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1322

Comment: I've seen this doc, but none of them address styled-components. It's a bit confusing for me.

Comment: you can't style this component with styled-components. Use you component api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used component api:

```
const customStyles = {
 option: (provided, state) => ({
 ...provided,
 borderBottom: '1px dashed #ccc',
 color: state.isSelected ? 'white' : 'gray',
 padding: 2,
 fontSize: '20px',
}),
control: () => ({
 // none of react-select's styles are passed to <Control />
 width: 500,
 background: 'white',
 height: 50,
 radius: 40,
 borderRadius: 5,
 display: 'flex', 
}),
singleValue: (provided, state) => {
 const opacity = state.isDisabled ? 0.5 : 1;
 const transition = 'opacity 300ms';

 return { ...provided, opacity, transition };
}
}
```

To customize the height, you change the heigh value in control, control represent the bar and from there you can change the properties using css and camelCasing. Then in your react-select component you import the custom styles by using `styles={customStyles}`.